# Sections over projective bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

I encounter a problem when I read compact complex surfaces.Let $X$ be a projective surface,$E$ is a vector bundle of rank 2 over $X$, $S \subset \mathbb{P}(E)$ is an irreducible subvariety such that $\pi |_S :S\rightarrow X$  is birational. It say that $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(E)}(1) \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(E)}(-S)$ is trivial on all fibres of $\mathbb{P}(E)$, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\pi|_S$ is birational, it follows that $S$ is a section of $\pi$. Hence we can write $$\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(E)}(S) \cong \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(E)}(1) \otimes \pi^* \mathcal{L},$$ 
where $\mathcal{L}$ is a line bundle on $X$. This implies $$\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(E)}(1) \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(E)}(-S) \cong \pi^* \mathcal{L}^{-1}.$$ 
Since $\pi^*{\mathcal{L}}^{-1}$ comes from the base $X$ of the projective bundle $\mathbb{P}(E) \to X$, it is trivial when restricted to any fibre.

Comment: Thank you very much, can you tell me where to find:
$\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(E)}(S) = \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(E)}(1) \bigotimes \pi ^*\mathcal{L} $

Comment: This is rather standard stuff on projective bundles. One has $$\textrm{Pic}\, \mathbb{P}(E)= \pi^*\textrm{Pic}\, X \times \mathbb{Z},$$ where the $\mathbb{Z}$ is generated by $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(E)}(1)$.
Have a look at Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry*, Chapter II, Section 7.